# Basic Join mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I've been working on this basic inner join for a little bit now, but I can't seem to get it to work. The question is:

> Given the CITY and COUNTRY tables, query the names of all the continents (COUNTRY.Continent) and their respective average city populations (CITY.Population) rounded down to the nearest integer.

The following SQL will query the average city populations of one continent but I can't figure out how to generalize it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cc.NAME, AVG(c.POPULATION) FROM
CITY c
INNER JOIN COUNTRY cc 
ON c.COUNTRYCODE = cc.CODE
WHERE cc.CONTINENT = 'a continent'
ORDER BY cc.CONTINENT;
```

[image: The City Table]
[image: The Country Table]

Comment: You `order by` is meaningless, because you get just one `cc.CONTINENT` with `where`

Comment: Is it your homework? I think you don't understand the task you qouted. You don't need per country rows, just per continent, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cc.CONTINENT, cc.NAME, FLOOR(AVG(c.POPULATION)) AS population
FROM CITY c
INNER JOIN COUNTRY cc ON c.COUNTRYCODE = cc.CODE
GROUP BY cc.CONTINENT, cc.NAME
ORDER BY cc.CONTINENT, cc.NAME;
```

Should work. I prefer to encode names etc. (but that's up to you and own personal preference):

```
SELECT `cc`.`CONTINENT`, `cc`.`NAME`, FLOOR(AVG(`c`.`POPULATION`)) AS `population`
FROM CITY `c`
INNER JOIN COUNTRY `cc` ON `c`.`COUNTRYCODE` = `cc`.`CODE`
GROUP BY `cc`.`CONTINENT`, `cc`.`NAME`
ORDER BY `cc`.`CONTINENT`, `cc`.`NAME`;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to get average population with its country name. So you use group by in query.

Use following query :

```
SELECT cc.NAME, FLOOR(AVG(c.POPULATION)) AS population FROM
CITY c
INNER JOIN COUNTRY cc 
ON c.COUNTRYCODE = cc.CODE
WHERE cc.CONTINENT = 'a continent'
GROUP BY cc.NAME
ORDER BY cc.CONTINENT;
```

Comment: Though the essence of your solution (`Group by`) is correct, I think you missed the "rounded down to the nearest integer" part; also it states "of all the continents" so I guess the `WHERE`-clause is not needed.

Comment: Can you give any example of your table with data?

Comment: just use `FLOOR()` for this

Comment: @Tony I think you need to ask Hossam ;-) But I assume the actual continents are in the DB (Europe, Asia, The Americas, Africa, Antarctica, Australia...). Also, as [stated by vp_arth](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37865775/basic-join-mysql#comment63188810_37865775) the `ORDER BY` is useless when the `WHERE`-clause limits the results to one continent.

Comment: @RobIII I used your suggestion to use the 'Groub by' and it worked great. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Rounded average city population is `FLOOR(AVG(c.population))`

```
SELECT cc.continent, FLOOR(AVG(c.population)) pop
FROM City c
JOIN Country cc ON cc.code = c.countrycode
GROUP BY cc.continent
ORDER BY cc.continent
```